# GWT Bootstrap programmatically reset ButtonGroup

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have a GWT Bootstrap `ButtonGroup` of radio type that I've created programatically in my GWT app.  The creation looks more or less like:

```
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(new Button("Button 1"));
bg.add(new Button("Button 2"));
bg.setToggle(ToggleType.RADIO);
```

This results in a 2-option selection box that is mutually exclusive.  Upon page load neither button is selected, however once a user selects a button there's no way to "unselect" or clear the choice.

I'd like to **programatically** reset the ButtonGroup to have no selection made (it has to be programmatic due to constraints I'm operating under).

The [ButtonGroup Javadoc](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/ButtonGroup.html) however seems to imply there's no method for "resetting" the `ButtonGroup`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to "deactivate" a button if it was "activated". Try something like this for each button (not tested)

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      if(button.getStyleName().equals("active"){
            button.removeStyleName("active");
      }
}});
```

Comment: Had to change the ```equals()``` to ```contains()``` as the button may contain other styles, but otherwise this is spot-on.  Thanks!